# Unable to connect to GitHub for 2 years, irregardless of network - any ideas?

Tags: windows, github

Toku here.

I've been without GitHub for 2 years now, and I'm getting sick of it.

In terms of web connection, I get a basic "This site can't be reached" - ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED.
Attempting to use the desktop app results in more information

[Image of 443 port error - more connection refusals.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W5k9H.png)

[Image of curl command result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dzeZw.jpg)

I'm running Win10 Home build 19044, connected to a private home network with no restrictions. What would be causing this?
Tried reconfiguring DNS, and it simply didn't change anything.
At the suggestion of FiddlingAway, I resynced my system time, to no effect.
For reference, I am living in the US, so there should be no issues connecting due to a countrywide ban. The web interface does not load, even on a VPN.

==LADIES AND GENTLEMEN, PROBLEM SOLVED==
So it seems I had some sort of silent, covert malware. It was doing something, something that I never got to figure out - but it was preventing both system updates and access to certain sites. I simply did not notice for literal years on end.

One day, recently, I realized that something was wrong when I couldn't update Windows. At all. I did a fresh Win10 install, and voila, everything fixed itself. Thank god it wasn't some UEFI rootkit thing.

Comment: This is very hard to diagnose without more information. For starters, can you see anything interesting in the output of `curl -ILv https://github.com/MapStudioProject/CTR-Studio.git`, such as a reason for refusal?

Comment: Also, can you access the GitHub web interface? Are you located in a country that might be blocked from accessing GitHub?

Comment: It might sound strange and unrelated, but bear with me. The issue might be related to your system time as well. If your system time is not in sync with the declared timezone on your machine, there would be an issue when checking the certificates. I've had problems [with downloading from Google Drive](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/104909/133629) (see my comment on that particular answer).

Comment: @FiddlingAway Resynced system time (it was fine but I resynced anyways), to no effect. Post updated.

Comment: @BenjaminW. I cannot access the web interface, and I live in the US. Post updated.

Comment: It says it's trying to connect to 127.0.0.1, that's your own machine. Do you have an entry for github.com in a routing table or something like that? Under Linux, I'd check `/etc/hosts`, but I'm not sure what the equivalent is for Windows.

Comment: @BenjaminW. The equivalent is $ route print, and there's nothing remotely associated with GitHub there.

Comment: Well, *something* is making curl try to connect to localhost instead of GitHub. Does `dig github.com` show a record?

Comment: What about your `hosts` file? Apologies if I'm suggesting something you already tried, but look into the contents of `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts` (with elevated privileges), and check if there's an entry related to GitHub. It should look something like this: `127.0.0.1     github.com`. If there's such an entry, delete it, save the file, and ping GH again.

Comment: Post updated. The problem has been solved. Thank you, @FiddlingAway, and thank you, Benjamin, for your contributions.